# Wordpress Widgets ampersand Problem

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have a problem with Wordpress. I want to create a text widget with title as

> Support & FAQ

But since I want to validate XHTML, I am writing it as `Support &amp; FAQ`

The problem is when I save the widget in iBlogpro Theme, amp is changed to simple & by Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using: `&#38;`?

**Edit** even if Wordpress changes the `&amp;` to & in the title of the widget, it will generate a `&amp;` in the HTML. So, your XHTML validations should not give you problems.

Comment: Which version of Wordpress are you using? I've done a simple test and it works fine. I set the title to be `Bla &amp; &ble` and the generated HTML code is the same.

Comment: I edited my answer. Have you seen the generated HTML code? If you keep having problems... can you share the URL of the blog you are working on so that I can see it closer.